# how do i uninstall one copy of multiple builds of a linux program

Tags: linux, qt

This has to be a common Linux conundrum:  I installed from source the Qt framework, and discovered later my Fedora distro has a native Qt build installed in the same /opt directory.  So now I have /opt/Qt and /opt/qt5_7 (my build).  How do I remove one and not break path dependencies, etc?  This is more my OCD wanting one-of-something-per-system, and there's currently no real symptoms of problems.  I'd just like to know.

Clearly this question can apply to a more generic "how to remove one-of-n builds of same program in linux" format

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to have multiple Qt installations side-by-side. Ideally, none of them would normally be in your path, to avoid any confusion, although many distributions only provide one Qt version and that one's `/bin` folder is often added to the `PATH`. When building a Qt-based project, you should always be invoking `qmake` explicitly for the Qt version you intend to build your project with. The generated makefiles contain absolute paths to the Qt installation folder the `qmake` was installed in. Corollary: Moving a Qt installation breaks it.

The `/opt/qt5_7` folder can be of course removed if you don't need it, there are no "path dependencies" (whatever it means) unless you've set them yourself.